# Encode a string to pass as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function:

```
function eLookup(type, long, lat, distance) {
//var sFilter = getCompanyProductFamilies();

distance = distance * 1000;
$.ajax({
    url: O.GenURL('xtmp_Maps/Get' + type + '.asp', 'long=' + long + '&lat=' + lat + '&distance=' + distance),
    success: eval('plotEntity' + type)
});
```

}

I have another function called getCompanyProductFamilies which I have commented out the call for in the above function as there is something wrong and this is partly where I'm stuck.

```
function getCompanyProductFamilies()
{
  var cb = document.getElementsByClassName("PRODFAM");
  var sAnd = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++)
  {
    sAnd += "comp_c_productfamily like '%," + cb[i].id.replace("pdfam_", "") + ",%' or ")
  }

  if(cb.length > 0)
  {
    sAnd = sAnd.slice(0, -4);
    sAnd = " and (" + sAnd + ")";
  }

  return sAnd;
}
```

The above function should get all checkboxes with the class name of PRODFAM, and for each one that is checked, it should slowly generate part of a where clause for a SQL statement. I am aware of the implications of SQL injections, but this is not something on the open internet, so ignore that. I tried several ways of getting the checked ones using jQuery but nothing I did worked.

An example of the HTML it is working on is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pdfam_711121" class="PRODFAM"/>
  <label for="pdfam_711121" class="VIEWBOX">Local Wage Rate</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="pdfam_711131" class="PRODFAM"/>
  <label for="pdfam_711131" class="VIEWBOX">Temporary Staff</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="pdfam_711341" class="PRODFAM"/>
  <label for="pdfam_711341" class="VIEWBOX">Other Contractors</label><br />
```

There are about 25 of the above categories, and this is just 3 as an example. The number of categories could change as well. What I need my my function(s) to do is:

Get a list of checkbox IDs that are checked and construct a string that can be passed as a parameter to the ajax call in the top function. When the parameter is received by the target of the ajax call, I can put a function in that page that creates the where clause for the SQL call.

Any help would be most appreciated. The top function called eLookup can't change too much but I can add querystring parameters, which is what I want to do. The other function it doesn't matter about that.

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: None. My function just doesn't seem to do anything. I know it doesn't look for just checked boxes at the mo. I'm happy for suggestions on how to get what I need.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/su9vt3xu/

Comment: In fiddle , same code works. probably Check for div's around the html markup?

Comment: I must be being dumb here but that fiddle... where does that output the text to? If I alter it to be an alert, nothing happens

Comment: if using chrome, open developer tools->console and check for those logs

Comment: Just found that :)

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere now. Thanks! I'll post updates in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that works.

```
function getCompanyProductFamilies()
{
  var cb = document.getElementsByClassName("PRODFAM");
  var sAnd = "";
  var bChecked = false;

  for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++)
  {
    if(cb[i].checked == true)
    {
      sAnd += "comp_c_productfamily like '%," + cb[i].id.replace("pdfam_", "") + ",%' or ";
      bChecked = true;
    }
  }

  if(bChecked)
  {
    sAnd = sAnd.slice(0, -4);
    sAnd = " and (" + sAnd + ")";
  }
  return sAnd;
}
```

As this returns a plain text string that is passed directly to an ASP page on the querystring, I may encrypt it. If I use encodeURIComponent, that makes it safe to pass onto the querystring, but still it can be altered. It isn't critical because of where the system is running, but I may look into something to safeguard the string.